# WMS Service Tilecache Python 403 error

Tags: ubuntu, python, http-status-code-403, request

I´m trying to migrate a Webserver + Mapserver to a new Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
Everythings (apache2, mapserver 6.2.1 ) working so far, except a tilecached wms service (tilecache 2.11-2 is installed) which needs an extra authentification.

When I´m calling the cgi script  (which deals the request) directly I get following
error:

```
    An error occurred: cannot identify image file
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 343, in cgiHandler
    format, image = service.dispatchRequest( params, path_info, req_method, host )
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 208, in dispatchRequest
    return self.renderTile(tile, params.has_key('FORCE'))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Service.py", line 138, in renderTile
    data = layer.render(tile, force=force)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Layer.py", line 436, in render
    image = self.renderMetaTile(metatile, tile)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/TileCache/Layer.py", line 397, in renderMetaTile
    image = Image.open( StringIO.StringIO(data) )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
```

I searched for hours, but cannot find a misconfiguration within the mapfiles or tilecache.cfg. All files should have correct permissions also. Unfortunately my access and error.log don´t tell me more about this.

My last guess is that something changed in python 2.7 f.e. different parameters (before we used python 2.53).

I know my question is a bit weak, but maybe someone had a similar situation. Or someone has a tip what else can be tested to find the error?

with kind regards,

Toni

Answer (score 0):

OH no! 
If anybody has the same problem,

check

```
allow_url_fopen =
```

in your php.ini
I turned it of for security reasons. Of course the WMS couldn´t work!!